# Register different model fields in another model's admin through foreign key

Tags: django

Is it possible to add `instructors` `Album` in user's admin page?

```
/instructors
model.py

class Album(models.Model):
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(Instructor, related_name='albums')

/user
model.py

class User(AbstractUser):
    ...

admin.py
    admin.site.register(Album)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `user's admin page`? I guess that you want an [inline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin)

Comment: how is `Instructor` related to `User` ?

Comment: @hack.augusto yes, its inline.

Comment: Hi, @karthikr somehow the `instructor_id` in `album` in a foreign key to `user` `id`